# Hiding a page from search engines like google (like Facebook's security settings)

Tags: asp.net, facebook, .net-4.0, seo, security

I am using asp.net 2010, and I would like to know how can I go about completely hiding a particular page from search engines, similar to how Facebook's security settings are set (for example, if I search for my real name, my fb page will now show up in google).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

For extra safety, you can analyze user agent string, and if it [belongs to a crawler](http://www.user-agents.org/), return an empty page.

Comment: I tried to explain this is a bad idea. go get a book like hacking exposed: web applications. You are basically telling hackers what you want to hide by using robots.txt.

Comment: @nick: if you want to properly *hide* something, put it under some authentication and authorization. you can't hide what is openly accessible. the only point of `robots.txt` is hinting search robots what URLs are bad catch, not what is secret.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of robot text you can hide a particular page from search engine..it tells the search engine spider, which Web pages of your site should be indexed and which Web pages should be ignored.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use robots.txt if this is a security measure. If you want to hide a certain page then this will tell attackers what you are trying to hide.